# How to search by prefix using a Spring JPA Specification?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm stuck on a JPA Specification task.
I have two entities, prefixes and country codes.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "prefixes")
public class PrefixEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String prefix;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prefix", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CountryCodeEntity> countryCodes;
```

```java
@Data
@Builder
@Entity(name = "country_codes")
public class CountryCodeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String countryCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "prefixes_id")
    private PrefixEntity prefix;
}
```

I want to get country code from "country_codes" table searching by prefix in "prefixes" table. I have already written a native query.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT cc.country_code FROM prefix_country_codes.prefixes p" +
            " JOIN country_codes cc ON p.id = cc.prefixes_id" +
            " WHERE p.prefix=?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> getCountryCodeByPrefix(String prefix);
```

How can I do this using Spring JPA Specification?

Something like:

```java
public interface PrefixSpecification<P> {

        static Specification<PrefixEntity> joinTest(String prefix) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<PrefixEntity, CountryCodeEntity> countryCodes = root.joinList("countryCodes");
...
        };
    }
}
```

and

```java
phoneNumberRepository.findAll(Specification.where(PrefixSpecification.joinTest("371")));
```

Comment: example filter by prefix.id `@Query("select obj from CountryCodeEntity obj where obj.prefix.id = ?1")`   try check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: Is using Spring Data JPA-derived queries a possibility?